# Функция TIME() в Sqlite3 возвращает неправильное время

Tags: sqlite

Создаю таблицу в Sqlite3:

```
CREATE TABLE session (
id      INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                 UNIQUE
                 NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
time    DATE NOT NULL
                 DEFAULT (TIME() ) );
```

При добавлении данных в таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO session (user_id) VALUES('4')
```

Запись выполняется, но время в столбце time не соответствует системному. И отличается ровно на 2 часа. Перезапускал ПК, менял системное время, результат тот же.

Comment: Функция [`TIME()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) возвращает время в часовом поясе UTC. Вы, вероятно, находитесь в часовом поясе UTC+2?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже разобрался. Необходимо указать параметры Time('now', 'localtime').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [`TIME()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) возвращает время в часовом поясе [UTC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F). Чтобы получить время в текущем часовом поясе, используйте:

```sql
TIME('now','localtime')
```